# matrix multiplication in c using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I'd like to multiply 2 matrix using pointers in c. The tricky thing is that I **must use** `gcc -Werror -o run filename file.c` in linux terminal, so I can't have even warnings in my code.

I have myArray matrix *n x n* (where n is even number - 4,6,8...), and I have to divide it in 4 parts, after that, I must multiply this parts like:

1x2=a, ax3=b and bx4=c (where 1,2,3,4 are the 4 parts of my initial matrix).

The problem is quite simple but I can't handle it.
The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
//---------------------------------------------initialize and adding elements!!!
void init_matrix(int **myArray, int n)
{
  int i,j;
    printf("Insert data:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &*(*(myArray+i)+j));
        }

    printf("The introduced Array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(*(myArray+i)+j));
          printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        {
    }

}

//---------------------------------------------devisation in 4 parts!!!
void first_matrix(int **myArray,int n)
{  int i,j,m;

    printf("\nThe first matrix is: \n");

       for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m/2; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(*(myArray+i)+j));
                  printf("\n"); 
        }
        printf("\n");
        {
    }
}

void second_matrix(int **myArray,  int n)
{  int i,j,m;

    printf("\nThe second matrix is: \n");

       for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
        for (j = m/2; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(*(myArray+i)+j));
          printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        {
    }
}

void third_matrix(int **myArray,  int n)
{  int i,j,m;

    printf("\nThe third matrix is: \n");

       for (i = n/2; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m/2; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(*(myArray+i)+j));
          printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        {
    }
}

void fourth_matrix(int **myArray,  int n)
{  int i,j,m;

    printf("\nThe fourth matrix is: \n");

       for (i = n/2; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = m/2; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(*(myArray+i)+j));
          printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        {
    }
}

int main(void)//----------------------------------------------------main function!!!
{
    int **myArray,i, n;

        printf("Enter the dimmension of Array: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

    //alloc memory
    myArray = (int **) malloc( n * sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i< n; i++)
    myArray[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));


    init_matrix(myArray,n);
    first_matrix(myArray,n);
    second_matrix(myArray,n);
    third_matrix(myArray,n);
    fourth_matrix(myArray,n);

     //some methods for mutiply

    //free memory
    for(i = 0; i< n; i++)   
    free(myArray[i]);
    free(myArray);

   printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code consistently, this is important to perceive the structure. As above, it's barely readable.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any C++ in your code -- this is a C question, yes?

Comment: What/where is `myArray1`?

Comment: `myArray[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));` should be `myArray[i] = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));` (but you have other problems also)

Comment: sorry, for myArray1... yes Cameron is just C

Comment: @MattMcNabb except without the cast.

Comment: Can you try to rewrite your problem description, it is confusing. Also, what is "m"? (You say the matrix is `n` x `n` then talk about `m`).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it was originally tagged C++ (and the cast isn't a mistake since stdlib.h is included; and imho the cast-less version is best used with the `p = malloc(N * sizeof *p)` form as there is visual checking that the sizeof is correct, and I didn't want to distract from the main point which was the forgetting of including `n *`)

Comment: yes it's nxm..
like it is - it's works.
So, I want to attribute each part of the main matrix(1,2,3,4) to the others matrix names (myArray1,myArray2,myArray3,myArray4) and then implement the multiplication algorithm.

Comment: Remember, matrix multiplication requires multiplying an (`m x n`) matrix with an (`n x p`) matrix that results in a product matrix with dimension (`n x p`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The tricky thing is that I must use gcc -Werror -o run filename file.c
>   in linux terminal, so I can't have even warnings in my code

For starters, **all** of your code should compile without warnings. Warnings are the way the compiler has of saying **"Your code may not function in a predictable way, or the way you think it will, until you fix this."** The compiler is rarely wrong.

Next, general matrix multiplication using pointers, simply requires that you follow the rules of matrix multiplication. That means you can multiply a `m x n` matrix (`matrix_a`) with an `n x p` matrix (`matrix_b`) with the result having the dimensions of `m x p` (`product matrix`). See [**Matrix Multiplication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) for details.

You will need to allocate space to hold the `product matrix`. The easiest approach is to declare a multiplication function that returns a pointer to the type required for the product matrix. You will need to pass `matrix_a`, `matrix_b` along with the `dimensions for each` in order to allocate, compute and return the `product`. The following is one approach to this implementation.

**Note:** since you are allocating space for the `product matrix` you are responsible for freeing it as well. Also **note**, it is advisable to initialize the `product matrix` to `0`. Choosing `calloc` for the row allocation can automate this for you without requiring explicit zeroing. (error checking below is shown, but not implemented)

```
/* 
    if mtrx_a is (m x n) and mtrx_b is (n x p), 
    the product is an (m x p) matrix
*/
int **mtrx_mult (int m, int n, int p, int **mtrx_a, int **mtrx_b)
{
    int **result = malloc (m * sizeof (*result));
    // if (!result) throw error

    register int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        /* calloc initializes all to '0' */
        result[i] = calloc (p, sizeof (**result));
        // if (!result[i]) throw error
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < p; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                result [i][j] += mtrx_a [i][k] * mtrx_b [k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how should I attribute a quarter of my main matrix to mtrx_a for example?

Comment: In working with sub-matrices, you either code logic to only iterate over the elements needed (e.g adjust i,j,k), or you can declare an additional pointer array and map the needed elements to the new pointer array. (you do not need to allocate additional storage and copy the original elements unless you plan on changing the values) You can then iterate over your values in the new sub-array directly.